# Changing columns from Nvarchar(max) to Nvarchar(4000) error

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table, nvarchar

I am changing columns from `NVARCHAR(MAX)` down to `NVARCHAR(4000)` the column has no need to be MAX and 4000 characters should be sufficient for the column, so for performance improvements I am making the column smaller.

I thought this would be easy like so:

```
alter table [MyTable]
alter column [Description] nvarchar(4000) NULL
```

However this gives me the error:

> The size (8000) given to the parameter 'Description' exceeds the
> maximum allowed (4000).

I dont understand this error message.. I did not specify `8000` nor did I even exceed the maximum allowed of `4000`

So whats going on here?

**Edit**

Some columns on tables / columns are fine with `NVARCHAR(4000)`, others.. are not, playing with the number 4000, the error seems to suggest the maximum I can specify on particular columns is NVARCHAR(2000)

Comment: whats the maximum length of character you have in description column , if you have any data

Comment: Are you sure this is in fact the code you are running? Do you have any DDL triggers?

Comment: The max length of the data in that column is `305`.. There could be DDL triggers.. let me check that

Comment: I don't think there is any performance improvement in shortening the declared length from `max` to `4000`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff oh really? Id be interrested if you had any further reading? I was under the impression that making NVARCHAR columns more specific would help the SQL engine and improve query performance. Everything I read says nvarchar(4000) is better for performance [Link](https://hungdoan.com/2017/04/13/nvarcharn-vs-nvarcharmax-performance-in-ms-sql-server/#:~:text=n%20defines%20the%20string%20length,1%20bytes%20(2%20GB).&text=%E2%80%9Cn%E2%80%9D%20in%20nvarchar(n,define%20nvarchar(max)%20instead.)

Comment: @user1 . . . I'm pretty sure that strings that fit on a data page are stored on the data page, which additional pages only used when necessary (here is a look at some timings https://www.sqlshack.com/varcharmax-data-type-walkthrough-and-its-comparison-with-varcharn-in-sql-server/).  In any event, this would seem like a micro-optimization, even if it did have an effect on the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be DDL triggers as suggested by one of the comments.

These DDL triggers are provided by a thrid party for data synchronisation to the client, so I'm not 100% sure what was going on in these triggers but I'd imagine they were getting some calculation wrong and thinking the max was `nvarchar(2000)` rather than `nvarchar(4000)`